# Twitter bootstrap popover: show all at the same time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

How can I show all the popovers on a page at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="popover" title="My nicer popover text">hover over me</a>
```

You should set the `trigger` option to `manual` and show your popovers unconditionally:

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({'trigger': 'manual'});
$('[rel=popover]').popover('show');
```